# Select a single object in a map Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'll start it apologizing for my English ^^

I have this code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRcoR.jpg)

```
data: function() {
    return {
        sabor: 0,
        cor: 0,
        teor: 0,
        beers: []
    }
},
methods: {
    
    findOne(){
        var menor = 150;
        var selecionadas = [];
        console.log(this.sabor, this.cor, this.teor)
        var goal = this.sabor + this.cor + this.teor
        console.log(`Goal: ${goal}`)

        this.beers.map( beer => {
            var score = beer.srm + beer.ibu + beer.alcohol
            console.log(`Beer score: ${score}`)
            var choose = Math.abs(goal - score)
            console.log(`Difference: ${choose}`)
            
            if(choose < menor){
                menor = choose
                selecionadas.push(beer)
            }
            
        })
        console.log(`Smallest difference: ${menor}`)
        console.log(`selected: ${selecionadas}`)
    },
```

As you can see, I have an array of beers.
Each beer have some data, such as alcohol, ibu and srm. The user will choose an amount of each of those specifications (by HTML) and I want to find the most similar drink.

I defined a variable goal, which is the sum of those 3 attributes. Then, inside of an Map, I add the beer attributes, and compare with the goal. The beer with smallest difference between the beer score and goal, should be the beer that our user is searching, but that is my problem.

I was trying to start an empty array, and pushing it with beers with the smaller difference (to goal), but this way it give me and array with Object object.

My question is, what can I do to, in 78 and 79 lines, SELECT the perfect beer (with smallest difference), to return to my user?

Comment: Post your [mcve]]

Comment: are you sure you are not just seeing Object object on console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to answer your questions.

> I was trying to start an empty array, and pushing it with beers with the smaller difference (to goal), but this way it give me and array with Object object.

This purely happens because you are printing it as string.
See:

```js
data = {
    sabor: 1,
    cor: 2,
    teor: 4,
    beers: [
      {srm: 1, ibu:1, alcohol:0},
      {srm: 1, ibu:1, alcohol:1},
      {srm: 1, ibu:1, alcohol:2},
      {srm: 2, ibu:1, alcohol:2},
      {srm: 2, ibu:2, alcohol:2},
      ]
}

function findOne(){
    var menor = 150;
    var selecionadas = [];
    var goal = data.sabor + data.cor + data.teor

    for (const beer of data.beers) {
        var score = beer.srm + beer.ibu + beer.alcohol
        var choose = Math.abs(goal - score)
        
        if(choose < menor){
            menor = choose
            selecionadas.push(beer)
        }
        
    }
    

   
    console.log(`selected:`, selecionadas) // <- instead of `selected: ${selecionadas}`
}

findOne()
```

I am not sure i am down to your second question, but, assuming you are searching for the *closest scored beer* you can use `reduce`

See:

```js
data = {
    sabor: 1,
    cor: 2,
    teor: 4,
    beers: [
      {srm: 1, ibu:1, alcohol:0},
      {srm: 1, ibu:1, alcohol:1},
      {srm: 1, ibu:1, alcohol:2},
      {srm: 2, ibu:1, alcohol:2},
      {srm: 2, ibu:2, alcohol:2},
      ]
}

function findOne(){
    var menor = 150;
    var selecionadas = [];
    var goal = data.sabor + data.cor + data.teor
 
    const selectedBeer = data.beers.reduce((ret, beer) => {
      const score = beer.srm + beer.ibu + beer.alcohol
      const choose = Math.abs(goal - score)
      if (!ret) {
        return {...beer, similarity: choose};
      } 
      else if(!Object.hasOwnProperty(ret, 'similarity') || ret.similarity > choose) {
        return {...beer, similarity: choose};
      }
      return ret;
    });

    console.log(`selected:`, selectedBeer)

}

findOne()
```

Comment: Thanks Itamar! The first option worked perfectly, but the reduce one is beautiful, and still works great :) 
PS: I didn't understand the part of similarity, what does it do to filter?

Comment: Similarity is just the difference between our goal to the score for each beer

Comment: Happy to help, please mark as answer for future readers